# Implement Different Expiry Dates on Documents in a Library

Tags: sharepoint, document

I need to be able to set different expiry dates for each document in a document library; some with no expiry date. What is the best approach for this? Information Policy Management or custom code? If custom code, how would I go about it, use a Site Column for the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to accomplish this with OOTB (out of the box) functionality. I created a document library and then created a "Custom View" for it. With the custom view, I was able to apply a rule for the expiry date (a column which I added to doc library). In the end it was pretty easy, though not very obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have MOSS, using expiration policies sure seems like the way to go.  As you probably know, if you don't have a date field in your library that you can go off of (even through some calculation), then you'll probably have to write custom code to determine the date.  But, this custom code is used by the expiration policy.

Comment: Hi Kirk,
That's the way I was thinking initially, but how do I relate a specific date to each document as it's being added? I'm currently trying to solve this by creating a Custom View on the document library. I'll post the outcome here :-)